# Unmanaged memory leak of OWSSRVR in SharePoint 2013 Windows Service

Tags: 2013, development, ssom, memory-leak

I have a Windows Service running on the SP2013 front-end server. The service uses SSOM API to access SharePoint Farm. In general, the service periodically gets some items from various site collections and processes them if necessary. 
The service uses the following SharePoint SSOM API Classes:

- SPSite in using clauses / try..finally blocks
- SPWeb in using clauses / try..finally blocks
- SPQuery to get items

We've noticed a raised consumption of memory when the service is accessing site collections and items. I've attached memory profiler to see what happens underneath and it showed the following:

[image]
[image]

The more times the sites are processed, the more unmanaged memory is allocated and not released. **I've made sure that every usage of SPSite or SPWeb is disposed.**

The question is:

What is the OWSSVR module and why it consumes so much memory?